# Python script outputs polygon feature class with no shape_area or shape_length and therefore doesn't show up in arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, cursor, feature-class, polygon-creation

I am trying to copy features a number of times based on a numeric field value.

The code below works for points when the POINT type is chosen. However, when I switched the feature type to POLYGON it correctly copies the features as many times as I want, but the polygons do not display when brought into arcmap.  For example, the output attribute table (shown below) is populated, but the SHAPE_length and SHAPE_Area fields are shown as zero.  Is there perhaps something in this code maybe within the input or search cursor '*' function that is not reading the shape_area and shape_length fields? The **input** feature class is a **polygon** and has a defined **shape_area** and **shape_length** for each record, which is not being carried over into the **output** feature class.

This table is from the output polygon feature class:
[image]

```
def main():  
import arcpy
import os  
fc_in = r"input.gdb\inputfeatureclass" # this one exists  
fld_count = "PHASE_COUNT"  
fc_out = r"input.gdb\outputfeatureclass" # this one will be created
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
sr = arcpy.Describe(fc_in).spatialReference  

# create the empty output featureclass  
path, name = os.path.split(fc_out)  
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(path, name, "POLYGON", fc_in, "SAME_AS_TEMPLATE", "SAME_AS_TEMPLATE", sr)  

# insert the features into the output fc  
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_in, '*') as curs_in:  
    flds_in = curs_in.fields  
    idx_cnt = flds_in.index(fld_count)  
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc_out, '*') as curs_out:  
        for row in curs_in:  
            cnt = row[idx_cnt]  
            for i in range(0, cnt):  
                curs_out.insertRow(row)  

 if __name__ == '__main__':  
 main()
```

Comment: When you run it on points, does it create the point features?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using cursors rather than just CopyFeatures_management?

Comment: It does run on point features no problem.  I am using a cursor because I am trying to insert rows based upon a field value, in this case the PHASE_COUNT field. Copy features wouldn't necessarily copy the features as many times as is listed in the phase count field would it?

Comment: The code looks good. Are you trying to insert point features into a polygon feature class?

Comment: That's good to hear. No, I am trying to insert polygon features into a polygon feature class.

Comment: "it correctly copies the features as many times as I want, but does not actually create polygons"... So does it copy the features or not? Do features display when you add the fc to a map? Is the only problem that the Shape_Area and Shape_Length fields aren't populated? If that's the case, then is the output feature class a geodatabase fc?

Comment: It copies the features.  It does not display when added to the map. The only problem is Shape_Area and Shape_Length aren't populated.  The output feature class is a geodatabase fc and does show up in the geodatabase after the script runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Polygon, polyline, or multipoint features can only be created using the SHAPE@ token."  This tidbit from the arcgis resource center helped.  I first updated the code to list all the fields in the feature class I was trying to copy (instead of using '*'), but instead of listing the SHAPE_AREA and SHAPE_LENGTH with all the  other fields I changed it say just 'SHAPE@' instead.  Problem solved..

```
def main():  
import arcpy
import os
env = r"T:\900.Users\Kerwin\HousinStudy\D1.gdb"
from arcpy import env
fc_in = r"T:\900.Users\Kerwin\HousinStudy\D1.gdb\central_sorted" # this one exists  
fld_count = "PHASE_COUNT"  
fc_out = r"T:\900.Users\Kerwin\HousinStudy\D1.gdb\central_sorted_out" # this one will be created  
sr = arcpy.Describe(fc_in).spatialReference
path = r"T:\900.Users\Kerwin\HousinStudy\D1.gdb"
name = "central_sorted_out"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
fieldnames = [u'OBJECTID', u'SHAPE', u'APN', u'STREET', u'CITY', u'SITUSZIP', u'JURIS', u'TMSA', u'TOD_CENTER', u'YEARBLT', u'DECADE_CLASS',\
              u'ZONING', u'LU_DESC', u'LU_CLASS', u'BLDG_DESC', u'SQFEET', u'FAR', u'TMRPA_ID', u'ALT_ZONING', u'ALT_ZONING_DESCRIPTION',\
              u'DEV_CLASS', u'DU_APPROVED', u'TM', u'TM_NAME', u'PUD', u'PUD_NAME', u'BUBBLE', u'ATOMIC', u'FINAL_MAPPED', u'MF_ID', u'DU_2013',\
              u'BUILT_DENSITY', u'TOTAL_DENSITY', u'DENSITY_CLASS', u'TMRPA_USE', u'VACANCY_STATUS', u'ZONING_CLASS', u'ZONING_CLASS_DESCRIPTION',\
              u'RESIDENTIAL_CLASS1', u'RESIDENTIAL_CLASS2', u'TOTAL_ACRES', u'UNCONSTRAINED_ACRES', u'NOTES', u'C_TOD_NAME', u'RSF_1', u'RSF_2', u'RSF_3',\
              u'RSF_4', u'RSF_5', u'RSF_7', u'RSF_8', u'RSF_9', u'RSF_10', u'RSF_11', u'RSF_12', u'RSF_14', u'modeledUnits', u'Model_Type',\
              u'Overall_Res_Suitability', u'ScenarioSubArea', u'ZoneName', u'MODEL_FLAG', u'MODEL_YEAR', u'MODEL_POP', u'PHASED', u'PHASE_COUNT',\
              u'SOURCE', 'SHAPE@']


# create the empty output featureclass  
##    path, name = os.path.split(fc_out)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("T:\900.Users\Kerwin\HousinStudy\D1.gdb\central_sorted", "input_layer")
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(path, name, "POLYGON", "input_layer", "DISABLED", "DISABLED", sr)  

# insert the features into the output fc  
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_in, fieldnames) as curs_in:  
    flds_in = curs_in.fields  
    idx_cnt = flds_in.index(fld_count)  
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc_out, fieldnames) as curs_out:  
        for row in curs_in:  
            cnt = row[idx_cnt]  
            for i in range(0, cnt):  
                curs_out.insertRow(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
main()
```